# How do I load a URL using a CSS file in my assets folder?

Tags: android, html, css, url, assets

I need to load a URL using a CSS file in my assets folder. When searching, I keep coming across code that looks like this:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", 
      string, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

But I'm not sure how to make it work. I can define the second string like this:

```
string = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" 
         + string;
```

Which seems to work at referencing the CSS, but how do I then pull in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSheetName.css" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```